# Intel Core M working temperature

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, fan, temperature

I have bought an Asus Zenbook UX305 laptop. This laptop is fanless, so I think this shouldn't get so hot, with Windows everything go fine, but I am running Ubuntu and this is getting hot, I've installed `psensor` and now I feel this is hotter (49 ~ 54 °C).

I have an Asus S46C and that was very hot when running Ubuntu, but that laptop has a fan, so no problem.

I am not sure if CPU is getting hot or RAM. My main doubt is:

What is the normal Core M (Intel® Core™ M-5Y10c CPU @ 0.80GHz × 4) working temperature?

Answer (score 0):

```
TJUNCTION   95 C
```

You're only around the 50% of the safe limit, its not a problem. My ULV i5s hover around 58-62*C when in use, perfectly fine.  If you start going over 70 its time for concern.

I suspect the delta between the two(if its not just perceived) is due to battery/power settings in windows limiting the clocks.